# Show that $E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])^2] \leq E[(X-Y)^2]$

Tags: probability-theory

Q: Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X \in L^2 (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{F} $ be a sub-sigma algebra of $\mathcal{F}$.

Show that $E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])^2] \leq E[(X-Y)^2], \ \forall Y \in L^2 (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}).$

Attempted solution:
Take any $Y \in L^2 (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$. Then

$$ E[(X-Y)^2]  = E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}] + E[X|\mathcal{A}] - Y)^2] $$

$$ = E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])^2] + 2 \underbrace{E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])(E[X|\mathcal{A}]-Y)]}_{\star} + $$

$$ \underbrace{E([E[X|\mathcal{A}]-Y)^2]}_{\geq 0} $$

where

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \star: E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])E[X|\mathcal{A}]] - \underbrace{E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])Y]}_{\star \star}
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

and

\begin{equation*}
    \star \star: E[XY] - E[Y[E[X|\mathcal{A}]] = E[E[XY| \mathcal{A}]] -  E[E[XY| \mathcal{A}]] = 0.
\end{equation*}

Hence

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
        \star: E[(X-E[X|\mathcal{A}])E[X|\mathcal{A}]]
    \end{split}
\end{equation*}

If I can show that $\star \geq 0 $ I'm done, but here am I stuck. Any hints?

Edit: Def:

$ Z = E[X | \mathcal{G}] $ if i) $Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and ii) $\int_{G} X dP = \int_{G} Z dP$, for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: You should state your definition of conditional expectation, since the property you are trying to show is often taken as the definition

Comment: In any case, a little bit of Hilbert space theory will help. For any closed linear sub space $F$, one has $\mathcal H = F \oplus F^\perp$. And moreover, recall projection theorem in Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Take your proof that $**=0$ and literally replace $Y$ with $E[X|\mathcal{A}]$ to give a proof that $*=0$.

In order for this to work, all we need is that $E[X|\mathcal{A}] \in L^2$, but this is also presumed in your proof of $**=0$ so I assume that fact is already in evidence.